# Recover Old Bitcoin Wallet (Currently getting a Segfault)

Tags: wallet.dat

I have a bit of bitcoin lingering in an old bitcoin wallet (circa 2011). I just restored it from a backup but I can't seem to load it into `bitcoin-qt`.

If I launch the app, shut it down, the copy in my old `wallet.dat` file and re-open, it shows a zero balance.

If, instead, I shut it down, copy over the entirety of my old `.bitcoin` folder, and then re-open, I get an immediate segfault. How screwed am I?

Comment: I would copy only the `wallet.dat`; everything else should be unnecessary.  Has your new installation finished syncing with the network?  Have you tried `-rescan`?  Also, was your old `wallet.dat` encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

You may find the following post relevant:

[Wallet.dat (<0.4.0) format: retrieving Bitcoin, possible security concerns](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37247/wallet-dat-0-4-0-format-retrieving-bitcoin-possible-security-concerns)

This post details some of the steps you may need to perform to import the wallet into a current client, the biggest time consumer will be waiting for the full blockchain to sync with the current network.

Answer (score -1):

This guy used some tricks way above my basic pay grade but, maybe something will help you

Good Luck ,

https://medium.com/@simonvc/i-found-an-old-bitcoin-wallet-1aeb2f32387a

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.